# Step detection in real-time 1D data

Tags: java, math, real-time, detection

For a small project we're trying to implement an autopilot for a slot car. A gyro sensor is attached to the car and delivers the Z-value (meaning the amount of centrifugal force acting on the car/sensor) 20 times per second. One crucial part of this is the detection of whether or not the car is in a curve or on a straight part and when exactly it was entered and when it left that part. Only so we can have reliable prediction of what'll happen in the future.

As for now, we're working with a sliding window to smooth the data and then have hardcoded limits (-400 for a left curve and +400 for a right curve) to detect what kind of sector (left, right, straight) we're in.
Obviously this takes too long, as it takes a couple of messages until the program detects that it's a direction change because of the smoothing and the hardcoded limits.

Here's an example of two rounds on a simple track, starting at the checkered area:
[image: Example graph]
[image: Example race track]

A perfect algorithm would detect the sectors S R S R S L S R S R S R S for one round, with a delay of only a couple of data points.

We thought about using the first derivative of the gyro values, but in the sample graph right after the first left curve, the following right curve (between 22:36:40 and 22:36:42) shows signs of swerving. Here the first derivative would be close to 0 and indicate a straight part...
Also, there we'd need to set a hardcoded threshold again, but with the noise of the data it could be that a small bump in the track could result in such a noise level that it's derivative would exceed the threshold.

Now we're not sure about what would be the easiest/fastest/most reliable way to handle this sort of detection. Would using a derivative be a good idea? Is there a better way?

Any input would be greatly appreciated :)

The existing software is written in Java.

Comment: If I understand correctly , the smoothing of the data is what's making it slower.And you need to smooth else you get "false positives". Can't you check other factors like angle for example in addition to force and at the same time ?maybe that way you wouldn't need to smooth data.

Comment: That is correct. So far we're testing our software on a Simulator but we'll have the chance to try it out on a real slot car race track, where we expect the noise to be a bit, well, noisier.
There would be other data to extract, but the Gyro-Z values are supposed to be the most reliable and noise-free ones.
Or what do you mean with the angle?

Comment: the angle of rotation of the car along the axis perpendicular to the ground (i suppose that's the y axis)

Comment: Ah yes, there will be some information about that but not in the simulator. As said, all other data from the sensor will be almost unusable, we're told... So we're trying to solve it by using the Z axis alone.

Answer (score 1):

In such problems, you have to trade robustness for immediacy. If you don't know what happens in the future, you can only make assumptions. And these assumptions may hold or may not.

From the looks of your data, there shouldn't be any smoothing necessary. If you define a reasonable threshold, the curves should be recognized quite reliably. If, however, this is not the case, here are some things you could try:

You already mentioned smoothing. The crucial point is how you smooth. An asymmetric smoothing kernel is probably desirable (a half triangle filter can be updated in constant time). You can directly weigh robustness and immediacy by modifying the kernel width.

A simple alternative to filtering is counting. If your data is above the curve threshold, don't call it a curve just yet. Count how many data points are above the threshold in a row. If there are more than `n` data points above the threshold, then you're most likely in a curve.

Using derivatives is potentially problematic. The main reason against derivatives is that a curve is not defined by any derivative at all (at least no derivative of the force). The second problem is that you can only estimate the derivatives numerically, which is quite unstable with lots of noise. So you would have to smooth your data (or find a numerical scheme for your noise model), which again requires some latency.